# Получить данные объектов JSONB

Tags: sql, postgresql, jsonb

**Что имеем:**
СУБД PostgreSQL 9.6 
Таблица сonfigurations со следующими столбцами `id` и `metadata`.

`metadata` - JSONB поле, в котором хранится массив объектов.

Пример содержимого `metadata`:

```
[
  {
    "request": {
      "id": 30003,
      "status": 7
    }
  },
  {
    "request": {
      "id": 30002,
      "status": 2
    }
  },
  {
    "request": {
      "id": 30001,
      "status": 1
    }
  }
]
```

**Что нужно:**

1. Найти все записи содержащие `status` равные 1, 2 или 3
2. Обновить значение `status` с 1, 2 или 3 на 7

**Мои запросы:**

Запрос на поиск записей у которых в `metadata` присутствуют `request` со `status` = 1

```
WITH obj AS (
    SELECT
        configurations.id as id,
        index - 1 as array_idx,
        jsonb_extract_path(
            jsonb_array_elements(configurations.metadata),'request'
        ) as data
    FROM
         configurations,
         jsonb_array_elements(configurations.metadata) WITH ORDINALITY arr(metadata, index)
    WHERE
      NOT (configurations.metadata @> '[{"request":{"status":7}}]'::jsonb )
)
SELECT obj.id, obj.array_idx, obj.data
FROM obj;
```

Получаем ответ в следующем виде:

```
obj.id | obj.array_idx | obj.data
1      |  1            | {"id": 30001, "status": 1}
1      |  2            | {"id": 30002, "status": 2}
1      |  2            | {"id": 30001, "status": 1}
1      |  1            | {"id": 30002, "status": 2}
```

**Проблема:** 
При появляются лишние записи. Причина: индекс объекта в массиве, но избавиться от него мы не можем, так как он необходим для последующей операции обновления значения.

**Вопрос:** Как исключить появление лишних записей?

**Используемые ресурсы при создании запроса:**

Документация PostgreSQL; 
[Статья](https://dev-gang.ru/article/kak-obnovit-obekty-vnutri-massivov-jsonb-s-pomosczu-postgresql-s036czh103/)

**P.S.** Структура упрощена, для пояснения проблемы. Знаю, что можно разложить JSONB в отдельную таблицу и не мучиться. НО передо мной стоит именно такая задача, поэтому прошу помощи/совета у комьюнити.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не уверен, можно ли проще, но пока как-то так.  Разбираем массивы,
заменяем элемент, собираем массивы снова, и обновляем все записи, где
они различны:

```sql
WITH configuration_metadata(id, metadata) AS (
  SELECT c.id, j.metadata
    FROM configurations AS c
         CROSS JOIN LATERAL (
           SELECT *
             FROM jsonb_array_elements(c.metadata)
         ) AS j(metadata)
)
, replaced_metadata(id, metadata) AS (
  SELECT m.id
       , CASE
         WHEN m.metadata->'request' @> '{"status":1}'
           OR m.metadata->'request' @> '{"status":2}'
           OR m.metadata->'request' @> '{"status":3}'
         THEN m.metadata || jsonb_build_object(
                'request',
                m.metadata->'request' || '{"status":7}'
              )
         ELSE m.metadata
          END AS metadata
    FROM configuration_metadata AS m
)
, new_metadata(id, metadata) AS (
  SELECT m.id
       , jsonb_agg(m.metadata) AS metadata
    FROM replaced_metadata AS m
   GROUP BY m.id
)
UPDATE configurations AS c
   SET metadata = m.metadata
  FROM new_metadata AS m
 WHERE c.id = m.id
   AND c.metadata <> m.metadata
;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
select id, metadata from tablename where exists (
  select from jsonb_array_elements(metadata) as el 
  where (el->'request'->>'status')::int in (1,2,3)
)
```

Для postgresql 12 можно ещё так через `jsonpath`:

```
select id, metadata from tablename where  metadata @? '$[*] ? (@.request.status == 1 || @.request.status == 2 || @.request.status == 3)';
```

---

Обновление можно записать так:

```
update tablename set metadata = (
  select jsonb_agg(
     case when (el->'request'->>'status')::int in (1,2,3) 
       then jsonb_set(el, array['request','status'], '7') 
       else el
     end) 
  from jsonb_array_elements(metadata) as el
  )
where ...
```